# Parsing HTML / Javascript into a MySQL database

Tags: javascript, mysql, html, parsing

I'm looking for suggestions as to the best way to parse the following calendar... http://www.ucd.ie/events/calendar . I can't detect any well known framework being used nor can I find it in RSS/XML/JSON format.

The only possible way to parse the following that I see is to parse the raw HTML which is far from ideal especially since many of the tags are repeditive.. a typical event looks like so..

```
    <tr> 
            <td class="odd"> 
                <a href="http://www.ucd.ie/events/calendar?dt=d.en.66031&amp;f=week&amp;d=19/10/2010&amp;sd=Wednesday, 06 October 2010 - Wednesday, 01 December 2010&amp;c=null&amp;c=null&amp;c=null&amp;c=null&amp;c=null&amp;c=null&amp;c=null&amp;c=null&amp;c=null&amp;c=null&amp;c=null&amp;c=null&amp;c=null">Exchange Information Talk</a> 
                <p class="description">Information for students on spending a period of study abroad on exchange as part of their UCD degree</p> 
            </td> 
            <td class="odd">UCD International</td> 
            <td class="odd">A105 Newman Building</td> 
        </tr>
```

As you can see parsing many of these from a HTML page isn't going to be fun. Basically I'm wondering does anyone have any suggestions as to how I'd go about this? or perhaps a smarter way of doing things? I'd really appreciate any help as I'm stuck can't really find any alternatives.

Thanks.

Comment: This has been answered [many times before](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=html+dom+parsing). Without knowing your specific technology, I can't make a more specific recommendation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the site does not provide another service then this HTML, your stuck with parsing it, but XPATH queries can make your live a lot more pleasant then just plain string matching.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with xpath , to get the link you'll do

```
//td[@class='odd']/a/@href
```

but it's gone break every time they change the hmtl ouput

Comment: is there no way of building something that'll automatically work for each case? the output will change daily.

Comment: No, that's why web services are made for, ask your university. And by "html ouput" I mean only the shape of the html tag, not the content, so I seriously doubt they will change it often (but they can).